# YII framework - Remove stripes in view form

Tags: php, yii

yii framework - remove stripes in view form??

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
        'data' => $model,
        'attributes' => array(
            'creationdt',
            'Objective',
            'period',
            'materials_required',
            'work_desc',
            'attachment',
            'Attention_Reqired',
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

Comment: your image is not loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `type` to define table type.

Generally Bootstrap CSS has 3 types of table classes. They are **striped**, **bordered** and **condensed**.

Bootstrap yii widjet defaultly has **striped** i guess. So, define the type on your code.

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
        'data' => $model,
        'type'=>'bordered condensed', //added
        'attributes' => array(
            'creationdt',
            'Objective',
            'period',
            'materials_required',
            'work_desc',
            'attachment',
            'Attention_Reqired',
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```